# How to change interface language in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, user-interface

How to change interface language in SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 1):

As far i know there is no language pack for SSMS.

But if you refer to the date presenatation thie is retrieved from **Regional and Language Options** for each run.

Comment: The problem is that I installed MSSQL Server Russian Edition, Then SSMS. Now I want have English variant.